# request.getParameter() returns null on submit button

Tags: jsp, servlets

Here I'm trying to click the button "submitAction" after click the js function DoSubmit() is called also servlet's doPost() method is called but inside  doPost() method the request.getParameter("submitAction") returns null where is I'm expecting it should return the buttons value either "Verify OTP" or "Resend OTP" based on which button is being clicked.

Following is the JSP code:

```
    <html>
<body> 
<script>
   function DoSubmit()
        {
            var btn = document.getElementById("submitAction").value;
            alert("in side the DoSubmit method and OTP is  : "+myOTP+ " btn clicked: "+btn);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : 'myservlet',
                data : {
                    myOTP : myOTP
                },
                success : function(myOTP) {
                    $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(myOTP);
                }
            }); 
            return true;
        }
    </script>
    <form name="submitForm" action="/myservlet">
        <div id="dialog" title="Enter the OTP">
            <p id="message">Enter the One Time Password</p>
            <p id="note"> OTP code generated will be valid for 10 Mins<p>
                <input type="text" style="margin-left:10px"  valign="right" maxlength=4 size=4 id="myotp" title="OTP" name="myOTP">
                <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Verify OTP" onclick="DoSubmit()"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Resend OTP"onclick="DoSubmit()"/>                   
                <button id="back">Back</button>         
            <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet class:

`@WebServlet("/myservlet") 
public class GetUserServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String submitAction = request.getParameter("submitAction"); 
        System.out.println(" "+submitAction);
    }
}`

Comment: ` String submitAction = request.getParameter("submitAction");` wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
  var btn = document.getElementById("submitAction").value;
```

The buttons with class "submitAction", don't have id attributes... 
You can't pass the value of a button like that without passing the event. 
You can pass it by doing this:

add 'this' to your onclick funtion of the input buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Verify OTP" onclick="DoSubmit(this)"/>
```

Then in your function you can get the value like this:

```
function DoSubmit(e)
     {
         var btn = e.value;
```

(make sure to add 'e' to the brackets of the function.)

Now the second problem with your example is that you are using a form but also making an ajax request.. What do you want to do exactly?

If you want to make an ajax request, remove the form tags. Because everytime you click on the buttons you submit the form, and you don't want that to happen because it will change the page you're on.

your html should look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function DoSubmit(e)
    {
        var btn = e.value;
        var myOTP = "123123"; //you don't define this anywhere in your example...
        alert("in side the DoSubmit method and OTP is  : "+myOTP+ " btn clicked: "+btn);


        var params = {
            myOTP : myOTP,
            submitAction : btn
        };

        $.post("myservlet", $.param(params), function(response) {
          //here you can handle the response from the servlet
          $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(myOTP);
        });
    }
</script>

    <div id="dialog" title="Enter the OTP">
        <p id="message">Enter the One Time Password</p>
        <p id="note"> OTP code generated will be valid for 10 Mins<p>
            <input type="text" style="margin-left:10px"  valign="right" maxlength=4 size=4 id="myotp" title="OTP" name="myOTP">
            <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Verify OTP" onclick="DoSubmit(this)"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Resend OTP"onclick="DoSubmit(this)"/>
            <button id="back">Back</button>
        <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```